# How can I manually position the hard drive head?

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I would like to manually position the head of my hard drive, just to hear the noise it makes.  I'll use an old drive just in case it breaks. Any idea where to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instruct your system to read a specific sector by specifying a number of sectors to skip, e.g.:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 skip=1500 count=1 > /dev/null
```

to read sector 1501.

Alternatively, you could use `hdparm` like so:

`hdparm --read-sector <sector> /dev/<hdd>`

That could bypass caching, and may therefore be better, but the startup-time is perhaps slower than `dd`